# how to create a sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to create a sqlite file when the application starts (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) the test if it already or not exsist otherwise create the file sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this... the sqlPath variable is the path to the pre-made sql database on your ressource

```
- (void) checkAndCreateSQL
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentPath stringByAppendingString:@"/database.sql"]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[documentPath stringByAppendingString:@"/database.sql"] 
                                                contents:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sqlPath]
                                              attributes:nil];
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

You can create the database on your mac using this command line :

```
sqlite3 database.sql < DATABASE_CREATION.txt
```

in the DATABASE_CREATION.txt something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` text,
  `position` integer
);
```

Then put directly the database.sql file into your project resource. (like an image)

Comment: But in this case you assume that the file to be created is already present, since you use a call to `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]`. Where should `sqlPath` be?

Comment: The handling of databases, unless where required by highly specific tasks, should be realized using the Core Data libraries, I think, since for using them you are not bound to specific SQL language implementation and specific database characteristics.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry... I mixed up names ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use the default Core Data libraries instead of manually creating and handling a single sqlite file. Please check the official Apple [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). It will automatically handle the creation and update of the inner database in the app.

Comment: I agree that Core Data should be in most case the API used, but sometimes you need a database with primary and unique keys, you can not just deal with Core Data without hassle

Comment: If Core Data couldn't easily handle unique or primary keys ... it wouldn't be there. It just uses an approach that is fully SQL-independent, as happens in Hibernate, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3 *reference2Database() {
if (_database == nil) {
    // First, test for existence.
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath] == NO) {
        // Database file doesnt exists. Copy the database at writable path (documents directory).
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.sqlite"];

        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:nil];

        BOOL databaseCopied = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!databaseCopied) {
            // Handle the error...
        }
    }else {
        // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
        if (sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
            sqlite3_close(_database);
            _database = nil;
            // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
        }
    }
}
return _database;
}
```

// Sample usage.

```
-(void) someDatabaseFunction {
   sqlite3 *database = reference2Database();
   // Do something with "database"...
}
```

// Close the database. This should be called when the application terminates.

```
void closeDatabase() {
if (_database == nil) return;
// Close the database.
if (sqlite3_close(_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    // Handle the error...
}
_database = nil;
```

}

NOTE: At the top of the file, you should have: static sqlite3 *_database = nil;

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Matteo Bertozzi's `SQLite Wrapper`**](http://th30z.blogspot.com/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper_8445.html) to create my sqlite database with the following code:

```
-(void)checkDatabase 
{
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:DBPATH] == NO)
    {
        sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc] init];

        if (![sqlite open:DBPATH]) return;

        [sqlite executeNonQuery:@"DROP TABLE yourtable"];
        [sqlite executeNonQuery:@"CREATE TABLE yourtable (record1 TEXT NOT NULL, 
                                                           record2 TEXT NOT NULL, 
                                                           record3 TEXT NOT NULL, 
                                                           record4 TEXT NOT NULL);"];

        NSArray *results = [sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM yourtable;"];
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in results) {

            for (NSString *key in [dictionary keyEnumerator])
                NSLog(@" - %@ %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
        }

        [results release];
        [sqlite release];
    }
}
```